# PlaneManagerApp - Overwriting on airlines

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

Hey im making a planeManagerApp.  I have a TreeMap containing Airline , HashMap(String,Plane);

I want the airline to print out planes belonging to it.  So for RyanAir i want 3 planes to print out for them and for AerLingus i want 3 planes to print out for them.  But when i run i get the Airline added last with all planes added.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class MainApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //PlaneStore map = new PlaneStore();

        Airline a1 = new Airline("Aer Lingus");

        Plane p1 = new Plane("A01", 150.5, 10.5, 500, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);
        Plane p2 = new Plane("B01", 50.3, 1.5, 91, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.CORPORATE);
        Plane p3 = new Plane("C01", 12.2, -3.1, 56, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);

        Airline a2 = new Airline("Brian Air");

        Plane p4 = new Plane("D01", 10.5, 1.5, 430, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.PRIVATE);
        Plane p5 = new Plane("E01", 0.3, 2.1, 101, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.CORPORATE);
        Plane p6 = new Plane("F01", 2.2, -3, 291, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);

        HashMap<String, Plane> airlineMap = new HashMap<String, Plane>();

        airlineMap.put(p1.getFlightNumber(), p1);
        airlineMap.put(p2.getFlightNumber(), p2);
        airlineMap.put(p3.getFlightNumber(), p3);

        airlineMap.put(p4.getFlightNumber(), p4);
        airlineMap.put(p5.getFlightNumber(), p5);
        airlineMap.put(p6.getFlightNumber(), p6);

        TreeMap<Airline, HashMap<String, Plane>> map = new TreeMap<Airline, HashMap<String, Plane>>();
        map.put(a1, airlineMap);
        map.put(a2, airlineMap);

        System.out.println("\n-------- PRINT KEY DETAILS --------");
        for(Map.Entry theEntry : map.entrySet())
            System.out.println(theEntry.getKey());

        for(Map.Entry theEntry : map.entrySet())
        {   
            HashMap<String, Plane> map2= (HashMap<String, Plane>)theEntry.getValue();

            System.out.println("\n-------- PRINT CLIENT DETAILS --------");
            for(Map.Entry theNextEntry : map2.entrySet())
                System.out.println(theNextEntry.getValue());    
        }

        //Plane p4 = new Plane("D01", 300.9, 45, 402, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.PRIVATE);
        //Plane p5 = new Plane("E01", 455, 23, 100, Plane.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);

        //Airline.airlineMap.add("Aer Lingus", p1);



       // map.put(Airline.getAirlineName(), p1);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The planes are never associated with a specific airline. You create 6 planes, give them flight numbers. Associate the flight numbers with the plane and then associate both airlines with the entire `airlineMap` hashmap.

```
map.put(a1, airlineMap);
map.put(a2, airlineMap);
```

This line is the only line that associates airplanes with airlines.

Comment: How would i associate them ?

Comment: That is a matter of design, style and preference. One way would be to create another hashMap using the planes (p1, p2, p3,...) as your keys and the airlines(a1,a2) as your values. When you iterate through this new hashmap, you should get your desired result.